# While installing the package pip install --upgrade scikit-learn==0.20.3 i'm getting a long error

Tags: python, python-3.8

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\anjba\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-72xp_tyn\\scikit-learn\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\anjba\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-72xp_tyn\\scikit-learn\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\anjba\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-un6d_aiv'
       cwd: C:\Users\anjba\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-72xp_tyn\scikit-learn\
  Complete output (678 lines):
  Partial import of sklearn during the build process.
  blas_opt_info:
  blas_mkl_info:
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
    NOT AVAILABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/12016 suggests using python 3.7 instead of 3.8

Note:
`No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils;` is the most important line of the error. It indicates that this error is related to numpy not scikit-lear (numpy is a requirement of scikit-learn). If you google this phrase you find the thread above and maybe some other helpful links.

Answer (score -1):

To solve this problem, you need to [create an environment in anaconda prompt](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands)

or

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.

Comment: Please use code blocks instead of images.